# How to apply weight curve with curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have two variables, and I am trying to use `curve_fit` in scipy optimize to fit the data. It looks alright, but the red line on the left portion does not fit so well to the data (green dots). How can I put some weights on the `curve_fit()` to shift the red line on left towards the blue line?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from pandas import DataFrame

x = [  57,   83,  124,  141,  196,  223,  275,  302,  341,  714,  895,
   1034, 1117, 1207, 1248, 1416, 1494, 1563, 1708, 1785, 1863, 2015,
   2139, 2238, 2312, 2412, 2442, 2520, 2596, 2658, 2706, 2777, 2846,
   2966, 3106, 3241, 3276, 3424, 3568, 3647, 3831, 3961, 4091, 4248,
   4430, 4478, 4644, 4833, 5052, 6041 ]

y = [ 70,  81,  87,  91,  96, 106, 109, 114, 120, 129, 144, 162, 168,
   175, 181, 184, 190, 195, 205, 213, 216, 219, 224, 226, 231, 236,
   239, 247, 255, 260, 264, 269, 282, 292, 297, 304, 308, 313, 319,
   322, 327, 333, 338, 341, 345, 354, 362, 364, 374, 391  ]
       

plt.scatter(x,y,color='green')

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x,b) 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'b-', label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

popt2 = [12.6, 0.386]
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt2), 'r-', label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt2))

plt.semilogx()
```

Comment: What do Vs and qnet actually represent? Is there a specific reason for your particular exponential model or could you use another?

Comment: Well, it's just labels, indeed x and y. Someone previously use exponential model, and I wanna replicate it. Surely it is open to use another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `sigma` in `curve_fit`. From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> sigma: None or M-length sequence or MxM array, optional
> Determines the uncertainty in ydata. If we define residuals as `r = ydata - f(xdata, *popt)`, then the interpretation of sigma depends on its number of dimensions:
> A 1-D sigma should contain values of standard deviations of errors in ydata. In this case, the optimized function is `chisq = sum((r / sigma) ** 2)`.
> A 2-D sigma should contain the covariance matrix of errors in ydata. In this case, the optimized function is `chisq = r.T @ inv(sigma) @ r`.

So you can consider a 1-D `sigma` as inverse weights. To better fit a particular part of the curve, assign lower values of sigma to the specific points:

```py
plt.scatter(x,y,color='green')

def func(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x,b) 

sigma = np.ones(len(x))
sigma[10:] *= 10  # set higher sigma for all data points other than the first 10
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma=sigma)

plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), 'b-', label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))

popt2 = [12.6, 0.386]
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt2), 'r-', label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f' % tuple(popt2))

plt.semilogx()
```

Which results in:
[image]

You can play with `sigma` to get better results than the above.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem necessary to add weights, but the model can stand to be improved by adding more degrees of freedom:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, Bounds

x = np.array([
     57,   83,  124,  141,  196,  223,  275,  302,  341,  714,  895,
   1034, 1117, 1207, 1248, 1416, 1494, 1563, 1708, 1785, 1863, 2015,
   2139, 2238, 2312, 2412, 2442, 2520, 2596, 2658, 2706, 2777, 2846,
   2966, 3106, 3241, 3276, 3424, 3568, 3647, 3831, 3961, 4091, 4248,
   4430, 4478, 4644, 4833, 5052, 6041,
])

y = np.array([
    70,  81,  87,  91,  96, 106, 109, 114, 120, 129, 144, 162, 168,
   175, 181, 184, 190, 195, 205, 213, 216, 219, 224, 226, 231, 236,
   239, 247, 255, 260, 264, 269, 282, 292, 297, 304, 308, 313, 319,
   322, 327, 333, 338, 341, 345, 354, 362, 364, 374, 391,
])

def model(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a * (x - b)**c + d

popt, *_ = curve_fit(
    f=model, xdata=x, ydata=y,
    p0=(1, 0, 2, 0),
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=(0,  -1e4,  0, -1e3),
        ub=(1e4, 1e4, 50,  1e3),
    ),
)
print(popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.semilogx(x, y, label='experiment')
ax.semilogx(x, model(x, *popt), label='fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

```
[ 1.75236837e+02 -2.67170725e+03  2.30138464e-01 -9.99999670e+02]
```

[image: fit]

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! So how do you pick those extra parameters, such as bounds and p0? Try different values? Really appreciate that.

Comment: The bounds and initial guess need to be chosen based on domain knowledge of the problem. I used wild guesses